# Camera activity does not return to parent activity when OK button is pressed.

Tags: android, android-camera

I just have a small problem. I open the Camera successfully and after I press the button to capture a picture, the following three buttons appear, `OK` , `RETAKE` and `CANCEL`. Normally when OK button is pressed the camera activity should return normally to the parent activity and perform what onActivityResult function contains. But in my case, when OK is pressed the camera activity does not return to the parent activity. Any sugesstions to solve this problem?

Please find below the code:

```
OnClickListener btn_TakePictureListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File imgPath = retrievePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(imgPath));
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode);
    }
};

//@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (RequestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           String s = data.getDataString();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "picture is taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }           
    }

private String retrieveName() {
    int []x = imgOpHlpr.getIDs();
    String s = imgOpHlpr.getImg_Name(x.length);
    return s;
}

private File retrievePath() {
    int []x = imgOpHlpr.getIDs();
    String s = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    s += "/myFolder/"+imgOpHlpr.getImg_Path(x.length);
    File file = new File(s);
    return file;            
}

private Uri getImageUri(File path) {
    Uri imgFileUri = Uri.fromFile(path);
    return imgFileUri;
}
```

Comment: so what happens when u click on ok

Comment: nothing happens the camera activity does not return to it's parent activity...as if onActivityResult does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement something like this..

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try{
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CameraCapture.this, Home.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: this does not work...and how startActivity is placed inside onActivityResult?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create directory you write image.
Add this line before you create file object.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/myFolder/").
path.mkdirs();
```